# How to connect Nuxeo 10.10 to Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, nuxeo

we try to connect a Nuxeo 10.10 server (with latest hotfixes) to our Keycloak server. The usecase is, that a user will authenticate against the Keycloak, gets a token and can use this token to call the Nuxeo API.
We found a Keycload login extension for Nuxeo on Github, but it doesn't work. Did anyone ever get a successfull connection between this two system and could help us with a short instruction?

Comment: You can just use OIDC to connect with Keycloak, take a look at https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/using-openid-oauth2-in-login-screen/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.